# How will i create a loop inside a button click

Tags: android, textview, android-button

I have 1 `button` and a `text view` .
i want to display the number `0-5` in the `text view` when each time i click on the `button`.

```
int index = 2;

                    switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                            // if we are using index 0, set the text to index 1 text and change index to 1
                            index = 1;
                            line2.setText(0);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            index = 2;
                            line2.setText(1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            index = 0;
                            line2.setText(2);
                            break;
                    }
```

i had tried most of the examples that available on the internet,but its not changing the value.
Anyone please help me to figure this out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: take a static variable and increment by 1 onClick of button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int mCounter = 0;
```

on **onClick()** of **Button**:

```
if(mCounter>4){
     mCounter=0;
 }
mCounter++;
txtInfo.setText(""+mCounter);
```

Hope it will help you.